# How to use ArrayList to find a name in a register

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently working on the following question:

> **Assume a class Name has attributes "surname" and "firstname" stored as Strings. Let "regist" be a list of Name with declaration:**
>
> ```
> ArrayList<Name> regist = new ArrayList<Name>();
> ```
>
> **Assuming that "regist" is populated, implement the method below that finds a name in the list with the given surname, or returns null if no
>   matching name exists in the list. (You may write Java code or a mix of
>   Java and pseudo-code).**
>
> ```
> public Name find(String surname)
> {
>   //... to do ...
> }
> ```

The answer that I have been able to come with so far is:

```
public Name find (String surname)
{
  this.surname = surname;
  return null;
}


public Name()
{
  surname = " ";
}
```

After that, I am stuck from here, if anyone can show me how to complete this code then your help would be truly appreciated, thanks in advance.

(I would be able to test this code properly if I am able to complete it properly).

Comment: There's no need to assign the surname parameter to a field (or anything) as you do now. You need to *iterate over the array list* and for each `Name` instance do what the assignment says.

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop over the items in `regList` and return the `Name` object with the given surname. Your current code for find is incorrect -- the find method is not in the name class and (or should not) be allowed to change variables inside a `Name` object directly.

At any rate, the solution is:

```
public Name find(String surname)
{
    for(Name obj : regList)
    {
       // Check the object's surname with the given one
       // Should check if obj is null
       // Must use .equals to compare strings.
       if(obj.surname.equals(surname))
           return obj;
    }

    // Not found
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to loop through regist and test if the surname matches the parameter... If the loop exits without finding a match then return null.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something along the lines of:

```
public Name find (String surname)
{
    // loop all names in regist
    for(Name n : regist)
    {
        // find the Name object with matching surname
        if(n.getSurname().equals(surname))
        {
            return n;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList you declared in 
`ArrayList<Name> regist = new ArrayList<Name>();` 
may already have the surename you want to find.  To find it you have to do the following in sudo code:

Find how many names is stored in  regist, then check every name from place 0 to the last place in regist. If it is the same, then return the first and surname. Remember that both first and surname is added to regist, and you should only test for the surename and return the both first and surename if surename is correct.

Comment: Ehhh no, the components of the name (first name, surname) are not added to the list. The `Name` objects are. You don't need to loop over the list to find the # of occurrences either, that's totally pointless and wastes computations.

Comment: True, U need to get the name object first, then test to se if the surname is correct and return it. The protocol also states that I would need to return a  Name object, not an array of name objects, so continuing searching would be a wast of cpu  cycles. If two or more have the same surname, just the first one will be found and returned as long as the metod declariation is public Name find(String surname)